# SnapKit with Auto Layout swift

Tags: swift, autolayout

I edited my application according to the iPhone X version. Other iPhone models because of the screen size of this image is corrupted. How do I edit the values I have defined according to the iPhone versions? For example, I share a sample code:

```
registerlabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 735).isActive = true
        registerlabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
       registerlabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 157).isActive = true
        registerlabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

registerlabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.chipField).offset(370)
            make.right.equalTo(140)
        }
```

although registerlabel appears on iPhone X, this label checkbox does not appear on iPhone 6.

I set chipfield's position with reference, but it didn't.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwGPP.png)

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of iPhone X and iPhone 6 ?

Comment: I add screenshot

Comment: As I can see the image, I think better work on multiplier. It will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm waiting for.

Comment: Do changes and let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: How to fix the problem, you were unable to help

Comment: Actually I can't see the actual view hierarchy. So it's quite difficult to fix the UI bug.

Comment: Do one thing, make a simple UI with important UI controls with constraints and multiplier and add in your post. Then I can debug the issue and may be I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then setting your `registerLabel` position from `chipfield` you should use the parentView bottom. This way you can have this working for any screen.

```swift
 make.bottom.equalToSuperView().offset(20) //Offset from bottom
```